# Andriod Studio - Sending data from Thread to Activity

Tags: android

I have a thread class which is gets data from NFC card and saves in the variable. But when i try to send an intent with the variable inside to start an activity i get error that cannot send by intent because required to have this.context which thread does not provide. Can some one tell easy way to send data from thread to activity.

I have tried to implement global variables, but that are not efficient way

Comment: please post some code of how you are implementing it! There are multiple standard way to run code in background thread and access result on MainThread

1. AsyncTask (deprecated avoid using this)
2. Thread with Handler
3. Reactive Programming with RxJava + RxAndroid
4. Coroutines (only if you are using kotlin as language)

Answer (score 1):

In Android, you should not directly manipulate UI elements or start activities from a background thread or a custom thread like you're doing with your NFC thread. To communicate data from a background thread to an activity, you can use various mechanisms provided by the Android framework. Here are two common approaches to achieve this:

**Using Handler and Runnable:**

You can use a Handler to post a Runnable to the main thread's message queue (= Looper). This Runnable can contain the data you want to send to your activity. Here's a simplified example:

In your activity, create a **Handler** instance of Main Looper:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

In your NFC thread, post a Runnable with the data:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Update your UI or start the activity with the data
        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", yourData);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**Using AsyncTask:**

A more structured way to perform background tasks and communicate with the UI thread.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, YourDataType> {
    @Override
    protected YourDataType doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Perform your NFC data retrieval here
        YourDataType result = fetchDataFromNFC();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(YourDataType result) {
        // Update your UI or start the activity with the data
        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", result);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

// To execute the AsyncTask:
new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```